# incrementing column values based on 2 other columns in SQL

Tags: sql

In this example table, I'd like to create the 3rd column (testNumberTaken) based on the test date and distinct person that has taken the same test x number of times.

I'm fairly new to SQL so any help would be great! Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (i.e. include code and an example of current data and expected output). Additionally, please [DO NOT post images of code/data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 1):

Please edit your question as per comment to follow a standard in SO.

Use Window function and try below.

```
select  person
      , testDate
      , row_number() over (partition by person order by testDate) as testNumberTaken
  from your_table
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a windowing function ROW_NUMBER() like this:

```
SELECT person, testDate,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY person ORDER BY testDate) AS testNumberTaken
FROM table
```

This should work in MS SQL Server and MySQL 8+

Answer (score 1):

This has to work.

```
SELECT PERSON, 
TESTDATE, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PERSON
ORDER BY TESTDATE) AS TESTNUMBERTAKEN
FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be quite as efficient but it uses a column made up of a subquery. An alternative to the two answers below.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS testTable;

CREATE TABLE testTable
(
    person NVARCHAR(50),
    testDate DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO testTable(person, testDate)
SELECT 'bob', '01/01/2020' UNION ALL
SELECT 'bob', '01/02/2020' UNION ALL
SELECT 'bob', '01/03/2020' UNION ALL
SELECT 'bob', '01/04/2020' UNION ALL
SELECT 'sue', '02/01/2020' UNION ALL
SELECT 'sue', '02/02/2020' UNION ALL
SELECT 'sue', '02/03/2020' UNION ALL
SELECT 'jane', '01/01/2010' UNION ALL
SELECT 'jane', '01/01/2019';

SELECT T1.person, T1.TESTDATE AS testDate,
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS TESTNUMBERTAKEN
    FROM TESTTABLE AS T2
    WHERE T2.PERSON = T1.PERSON 
        AND T2.TESTDATE <= T1.TESTDATE
    GROUP BY PERSON
) 
FROM TESTTABLE AS T1
ORDER BY PERSON ASC, TESTDATE ASC;
```

Comment: FYI your `INSERT` can be rewritten like `INSERT INTO testTable (person, testData) VALUES ('bob', '01/01/2020'), ('bob', '01/02/2020'), ... ;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use DENSE_RANK() to get multiple occurrences on same day.

```
SELECT PERSON, 
TESTDATE, 
DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY PERSON
ORDER BY TESTDATE) AS TESTNUMBERTAKEN
FROM TABLE_NAME;
```